# How do I make use of environment variables on tags

Tags: tags, environment-variables, fluentd

How do I make use of environment vars in tags

`tag raw.kubernetes.*."#{ENV['ENVIRONMENT']}"."#{ENV['REGION']}"`

```
    <source>
      @id fluentd-containers.log
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/es-containers.log.pos
      tag raw.kubernetes.*."#{ENV['ENVIRONMENT']}"."#{ENV['REGION']}"
```

Tags shows up in elasticsearch as

`kubernetes.var.log.containers.aoo-web-qa3-b5b47b6d5-w76c2_default_app-web-fd68c32c550064d866ec2e514fe153e2bdda5a0849dbc10ecedc2c6ff30bc549.log."#{ENV['ENVIRONMENT']}"."#{ENV['REGION']}"`

Comment: Can you try like this?. `tag "raw.kubernetes.*.#{ENV['ENVIRONMENT']}.#{ENV['REGION']}"` which is moving quotes outside. Let me know if this works, I will put it as answer.

Comment: That was it! Never occurred to me to move the quotes to either end. Thanks much

Comment: Cool. I added it as answer, you can accept if if you are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, you need to move quotes outside tag value which makes sure environment variables are picked. Example -

```
tag "raw.kubernetes.*.#{ENV['ENVIRONMENT']}.#{ENV['REGION']}"
```